# About subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ as vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, extension-field, real-numbers, rational-numbers

In many texts is noted the analogy between the transcendence degree of a field extension and the dimension of a vector space, so I'm tempting to use such analogy to better understand the structure of $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, using the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is also a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Given a subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}$, the $\Bbb Q$-vector space $V_S= \operatorname{span}_{\Bbb Q} (S)$, as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, has dimension $dim (V_S)$ that can be finite or infinite (denumerable or not).

We have also the extension field $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ that has a transcendence degree $Trd (\mathbb{Q}(S))$.

My question is if there exists some relation between these.

It seems to me that we can not have, in general: $dim (V_S)=Trd (\mathbb{Q}(S))$. A simple counter example being $S=\{\sqrt{2},\pi\}$.
But there is some way to characterize the cases in which the identity is valid?

We can prove that $dim (V_S) \ge Trd (\mathbb{Q}(S))$ ? And there is some way to compare this two values when they are infinite?

I will appreciate also any reference to sources where I can find a review of known results about the vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What do you mean we can prove $\dim(V_S)\le\operatorname{Trd}(\Bbb Q(S))$, your own counterexample falsifies this. $S=\{\sqrt{2},\pi\}$ has transcendence degree $1$ but infinite vector space degree. In general **any** transcendentals in $S$ imply $\dim V_S=\infty$, so that there's no hope of the inequality in the direction you are hoping, and I think very little non-trivial to say in the opposite direction as well.

Comment: Sorry: Typo in the inequality direction! I edit.

Comment: I added an elementary-set-theory tag to give it some exposure to some of  those familiar with cardinal arithmetic and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can prove that 
$$ Trd (\mathbb{Q}(S)) \aleph_0 + 1 \le   \dim (\mathbb{Q}(S)) \le (Trd (\mathbb{Q}(S)) +1) \aleph_0 .$$
In particular $\dim (\mathbb{Q}(S)) = Trd (\mathbb{Q}(S))  \aleph_0$  if $Trd (\mathbb{Q}(S))$ is non-zero.

Let $S'  \subset S$ be a transcendence basis of $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ then $S'$ is algebraically indepenent over the rationals and thus in particular $\{s^n \colon n>0, s \in S'\} \cup \{1\}$ is linearly independent over the rationals. Showing the one inequality.

In the other direction on gets $| \mathbb{Q}(S') | = \max\{\aleph_0, |S'|\}$ and $|\mathbb{Q}(S)| \le | \mathbb{Q}(S') | \ \aleph_0 $ as the extension $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(S')$ is algebraic.

In the same way, one can show that 
$$\dim V_S \ge Trd (\mathbb{Q}(S)).$$
A transcendence basis (over the rationals) is algebraically independent and thus in particular linearly independent (over the rationals).

However, in general this inequality will be strict. When $s$ is transcendental then setting $S_i = \{s^i \colon 1 \le i < n+1\}$, 
we get that $\dim V_{S_i} = i$ while $Trd (\mathbb{Q}(S_i)) = 1$.

So we get any finite dimension as well as a countable dimension with transcendence degree $1$ (we could even do it with transcendence degree $0$).

Yet our upper bound above shows that the discrepancy is at most countable since $V_S \subset \mathbb{Q}(S)$.

So, as soon as $ Trd (\mathbb{Q}(S)) \ge \aleph_0$ we have $ Trd (\mathbb{Q}(S)) = \dim V_S$.

(This uses AC, I guess)

Comment: You guess correctly, the cardinal equalities do require the axiom of choice.

Comment: @quid: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to well understand it and I have some trouble with my intuition. If $S=\{\pi\}$ I think, intuitively, that the dimension of the vector space generated by $\pi$ is $1$, since it is the only element of the basis, but this does not fit with your result (correct?), so where my intuition fails?

Comment: @EmilioNovati sorry I mixed up badly your notations. I will fix that ASAP.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I hope things are fixed now and thus make more sense now.